# Troubleshooting Symbol Placement Logic in JavaScript Tic-Tac-Toe Game

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

```js
const gameMenu = document.querySelector('.game-menu');
const gameBoard = document.querySelector('.game-board');
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
const turnIndicator = document.querySelector('.turn-indicator');
const tieScoreboard = document.querySelector('.tie-score')
const gameOverMenu = document.querySelector('.game-over-menu');
const gameResultMessage = document.querySelector('.game-over-message');
const playerSymbolSwitch = document.getElementById('player-symbol-switch');
let currentPlayer;
let isVsCpu = false;
let gameActive = false;
 

let gameScoreBoard = {
    singlePlayerWins:0,
    cpuWins: 0,
    singlePlayerTies:0,
    playerOneWins: 0,
    playerTwoWins: 0,
    multiPlayerTies: 0

}

function startGame(vsCpu) {
    isVsCpu = vsCpu;
    setPlayerSymbol();
    gameActive = true;
    resetGameBoard();
    gameMenu.style.display = 'none';
    gameBoard.style.display = 'flex';
    updateTurnIndicator();
    if (isVsCpu && currentPlayer === 'O') {
        cpuMove();
    }
}

function setPlayerSymbol() {
    currentPlayer = playerSymbolSwitch.checked ? 'O' : 'X';
    // Assign "You" or "CPU" to "X" and "O" based on currentPlayer for single-player
    if (isVsCpu) {
        playerX = currentPlayer === 'X' ? 'You' : 'CPU';
        playerO = currentPlayer === 'O' ? 'You' : 'CPU';
    } else {
        // In multiplayer mode, determine Player 1 and Player 2's symbols based on currentPlayer
        if (currentPlayer === 'X') {
            playerX = 'Player 1';
            playerO = 'Player 2';
        } else {
            playerX = 'Player 2';
            playerO = 'Player 1';
        }
    }
    console.log(playerO +': Player 0  ' + playerX + ' :Player X' + '-----setPlayerSymbol ')
}

// Update the turn indicator based on the current player and game mode
function updateTurnIndicator() {
    turnIndicator.textContent = gameActive ? `${currentPlayer} Turn` : 'Game Over';
}


function handleCellClick(index) {
    if (!gameActive || cells[index].textContent) return;
    // Determine the symbol to use based on the current player's role
    const symbolToUse = currentPlayer === 'X' ? playerX : playerO;
    makeMove(index, symbolToUse); // Use the determined symbol for making a move
    if (gameActive && isVsCpu && currentPlayer === 'O') {
        setTimeout(cpuMove, 500);
    }
}

// Update the scoreboard to reflect the correct labels for single or multiplayer
function updateScoreboard() {
    // Determine who is Player 1, Player 2, "You", or "CPU" and their symbols
    let player1Label, player2Label;
    const playerXSymbol = playerSymbolSwitch.checked ? 'O' : 'X';
    const playerOSymbol = playerXSymbol === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';

    if (isVsCpu) {
        player1Label = `You (${playerXSymbol})`;
        player2Label = `CPU (${playerOSymbol})`;
    } else {
        player1Label = `Player 1 (${playerXSymbol})`;
        player2Label = `Player 2 (${playerOSymbol})`;
    }

    // Scores
    let p1Score = isVsCpu ? (playerXSymbol === 'X' ? gameScoreBoard.singlePlayerWins : gameScoreBoard.cpuWins) : gameScoreBoard.playerOneWins;
    let p2Score = isVsCpu ? (playerOSymbol === 'O' ? gameScoreBoard.cpuWins : gameScoreBoard.singlePlayerWins) : gameScoreBoard.playerTwoWins;
    let tieScore = isVsCpu ? gameScoreBoard.singlePlayerTies : gameScoreBoard.multiPlayerTies;

    // Update Player 1 Score
    document.querySelector('.p1-score').textContent = `${player1Label}: `;
    let p1Span = document.querySelector('.p1-score span');
    if (!p1Span) {
        p1Span = document.createElement('span');
        document.querySelector('.p1-score').appendChild(p1Span);
    }
    p1Span.textContent = p1Score;

    // Update Player 2 Score
    document.querySelector('.p2-score').textContent = `${player2Label}: `;
    let p2Span = document.querySelector('.p2-score span');
    if (!p2Span) {
        p2Span = document.createElement('span');
        document.querySelector('.p2-score').appendChild(p2Span);
    }
    p2Span.textContent = p2Score;

    // Update Ties Score
    document.querySelector('.tie-score').textContent = `Ties: `;
    let tieSpan = document.querySelector('.tie-score span');
    if (!tieSpan) {
        tieSpan = document.createElement('span');
        document.querySelector('.tie-score').appendChild(tieSpan);
    }
    tieSpan.textContent = tieScore;
}


function makeMove(index, playerRole) {
    // Based on playerRole, decide whether to place 'X' or 'O'
    const symbol = (playerRole === playerX || playerRole === 'You' && playerX === 'You') ? 'X' : 'O';
    cells[index].textContent = symbol; // Place the symbol on the board

    let winnerSymbol = checkWin(); // Check for a win, returns 'X', 'O', or null

    if (winnerSymbol) {
        gameActive = false;
        endGame(`${winnerSymbol} wins!`);
        updateScores(winnerSymbol); // Update scores with the winning symbol
    } else if (checkTie()) {
        gameActive = false;
        endGame("It's a tie!");
        updateScores("Tie"); // Update scores for a tie
    } else {
        // Switch currentPlayer based on the actual symbol placed
        currentPlayer = symbol === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
        updateTurnIndicator();
        if (isVsCpu && currentPlayer === 'O') {
            setTimeout(cpuMove, 500);
        }
    }
}


function updateScores(winnerSymbol) {
    // Use playerX and playerO to increment the correct score
    if (winnerSymbol === 'X') {
        if (isVsCpu) {
            gameScoreBoard[playerX === 'You' ? 'singlePlayerWins' : 'cpuWins']++;
        } else {
            gameScoreBoard[playerX === 'Player 1' ? 'playerOneWins' : 'playerTwoWins']++;
        }
    } else if (winnerSymbol === 'O') {
        if (isVsCpu) {
            gameScoreBoard[playerO === 'You' ? 'singlePlayerWins' : 'cpuWins']++;
        } else {
            gameScoreBoard[playerO === 'Player 1' ? 'playerOneWins' : 'playerTwoWins']++;
        }
    } else if (winnerSymbol === 'Tie') {
        isVsCpu ? gameScoreBoard.singlePlayerTies++ : gameScoreBoard.multiPlayerTies++;
    }
    console.log(winnerSymbol)
    console.log(playerO + ':player O')
    console.log(playerX + ':player X')
    console.log(gameScoreBoard)
    updateScoreboard();
}



function cpuMove() {
    // Ensure that CPU only moves if it's their turn
    if (!isVsCpu || !gameActive || currentPlayer !== 'O') return;

    let available = [...cells].filter(cell => !cell.textContent);
    if (available.length) {
        const choice = available[Math.floor(Math.random() * available.length)];
        makeMove([...cells].indexOf(choice), 'O');
    }
}

function resetGameBoard() {
    cells.forEach(cell => cell.textContent = '');
    gameActive = true;
    setPlayerSymbol();
    updateTurnIndicator();
    updateScoreboard()
    
}

function checkWin() {
    const winPatterns = [
        [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]
    ];

    for (let pattern of winPatterns) {
        const [a, b, c] = pattern;
        if (cells[a].textContent && cells[a].textContent === cells[b].textContent && cells[a].textContent === cells[c].textContent) {
            return cells[a].textContent; // Return the winning symbol ('X' or 'O')
        }
    }

    return null; // No winner found
}


function checkTie() {
    return [...cells].every(cell => cell.textContent);
}

function endGame(winnerSymbol) {
    let resultMessage;
    if (winnerSymbol) {
        let winner = winnerSymbol === currentPlayer ? 'You' : (isVsCpu ? 'CPU' : 'Player 2');
        resultMessage = `${winner} wins!`;
    } else {
        resultMessage = "It's a tie!";
    }

    updateScores(winnerSymbol); // Update scores with the winner symbol or tie
    displayEndGame(resultMessage); // Display the end game message
}

function displayEndGame(resultMessage) {
    gameResultMessage.textContent = resultMessage;
    gameOverMenu.style.display = 'flex';
}
function endGame(resultMessage) {
    gameActive = false;
    displayEndGame(resultMessage);
    // updateScores(currentPlayer);
}

function displayEndGame(resultMessage) {
    // Show the game over menu and update messages
    gameResultMessage.textContent = resultMessage;
    gameOverMenu.style.display = 'flex';
}
    
// Button event listeners
document.querySelector('.quit').addEventListener('click', () => {
    gameBoard.style.display = 'none';
    gameOverMenu.style.display = 'none';
    gameMenu.style.display = 'flex'; // Show the main menu
});

document.querySelector('.next-round').addEventListener('click', () => {
    resetGameBoard(); // Reset and start a new game round
    updateTurnIndicator()
    gameOverMenu.style.display = 'none';
});

document.querySelector('.yes-restart').addEventListener('click', () => {
    resetGameBoard(); // Reset and start a new game
    updateTurnIndicator()
    gameOverMenu.style.display = 'none';
    gameMenu.style.display = 'none'; 
});

document.querySelector('.no-cancel').addEventListener('click', () => {
    gameOverMenu.style.display = 'none'; 
    gameMenu.style.display = 'flex'; 
    gameBoard.style.display = 'none';
});

document.querySelector('.reset-button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    resetGameBoard()
    updateTurnIndicator()
    gameOverMenu.style.display = 'none';
    gameMenu.style.display = 'none';
})

document.getElementById('start-cpu').addEventListener('click', () => startGame(true));
document.getElementById('start-player').addEventListener('click', () => startGame(false));

cells.forEach((cell, index) => cell.addEventListener('click', () => handleCellClick(index)));
```

```css
/* Basic Reset */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
  
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
  
.game-container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.game-menu {
    
}

.game-board {
    display: none;
}

.game-over-menu {
    display: none;
}

.game-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.game-cells {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.cell {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #16213e;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.game-footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.scoreboard {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.score {
  
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.score span{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="game-container">
    
    <!-- New game menu start -->
    <div class="game-menu container">
      <p>Pick player 1's mark. Remember: X goes first.</p>
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="player-symbol-switch">
        <span class="slider round"></span> Play as X
      </label>
      <button id="start-cpu">New Game (vs CPU)</button>
      <button id="start-player">New Game (vs Player)</button>
    </div>

    <!-- New game menu end -->

    <!-- Game board start -->
    <div class="game-board container">
      
      <div class="game-header">
        <div class="player-indicator">XO</div>
        <div class="turn-indicator">X TURN</div>
        <div class="reset-button">⟳</div>
      </div>

      <div class="game-cells">
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
        <div class="cell"></div>
      </div>
      

      <div class="game-footer">
        <div class="scoreboard">
          <!-- Player 1 Score -->
          <div class="score p1-score">
            <!-- Static text will be set by JavaScript; Span for dynamic score value -->
            <span>0</span>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Ties Score -->
          <div class="score tie-score">
            TIES <span>0</span>
          </div>
          
          <!-- Player 2 Score -->
          <div class="score p2-score">
            <!-- Static text will be set by JavaScript; Span for dynamic score value -->
            <span>0</span>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Game board end -->

    <div class="game-over-menu container">
      <div>
        <div>
          <p><span class="game-over-message"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Player <span class="winner-player"></span> wins!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <span class="round-result-message"></span>
        Round tied
        Restart game?
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <button class="quit">Quit</button>
        <button class="next-round">Next Round</button>
        <button class="no-cancel">No, cancel</button>
        <button class="yes-restart">Yes, restart</button>
    </div>

    </div>
```

I'm building a Tic-Tac-Toe game in JavaScript, where players can choose to play against the CPU or another player. Players can choose to be 'X' or 'O'. I've encountered an issue in single-player mode when the player chooses to be 'O'. Despite selecting 'O', the game incorrectly assigns 'X' to the player for their moves.

I'm looking for insights into what might be going wrong with my symbol assignment and CPU move logic. How can I ensure that the symbols are correctly assigned based on the player's choice, and the CPU acts accordingly?

Additional Context:

JavaScript ES6
The game switches between 'X' and 'O' for currentPlayer after each move.
**CODEPEN LINK**: [CODE PEN LINK](https://codepen.io/Day-Fiveseven/pen/gOEZeRd)

Here's a simplified version of my code relevant to the problem:

```
let currentPlayer;
let playerX = 'Player 1';
let playerO = 'Player 2';
let isVsCpu = false;

// Set up based on player choice
function setPlayerSymbol() {
    currentPlayer = playerSymbolSwitch.checked ? 'O' : 'X';
    if (isVsCpu) {
        playerX = currentPlayer === 'X' ? 'You' : 'CPU';
        playerO = currentPlayer === 'O' ? 'You' : 'CPU';
    }
}

function cpuMove() {
    if (!isVsCpu || !gameActive || currentPlayer === playerX) return;
    const cpuSymbol = playerX === 'CPU' ? 'X' : 'O';
    // CPU move logic here
}

function handleCellClick(index) {
    if (!gameActive || cells[index].textContent) return;
    const symbolToUse = currentPlayer === 'X' ? playerX : playerO;
    makeMove(index, symbolToUse);
}

function makeMove(index, symbol) {
    cells[index].textContent = symbol;
    // Check win or tie logic here
}
```

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Attempted Solutions:

Ensured setPlayerSymbol correctly assigns 'X' or 'O' based on the player's selection.
Adjusted cpuMove to consider playerX and playerO for determining the symbol to use.
Tweaked handleCellClick to use the correct symbol for player moves.
Despite these adjustments, the game still misassigns the symbols. The CPU also fails to make moves when the player selects 'O'.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here instead of a CodePen link. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: You never call `setPlayerSymbol()`.

Comment: When I tried your codepen I couldn't see the moves. Black text on a dark background is almost invisible.

Comment: i called the setPlayerSymbol in the startGame(), is there anywhere else youd recommend including it ? i also have to edit the css as well i wanted to get the logic down beofre i really customized it

Comment: This is backwards: `currentPlayer = playerSymbolSwitch.checked ? 'O' : 'X';`. When the box is checked they want to be X, not O.

Comment: It should be `currentPlayer = playerSymbolSwitch.checked ? 'X' : 'O';`

Comment: I flipped because it was going to look different after i added the css, everything is working how I want it to as far as logic but, its when u select the option to be "O" on the single player mode its still placing down an "X" for me on the board , i still am being counted as "O" in the console , and im going after the CPu since they are "X" is just that one modes that has this bug

Comment: The code is very confusing because you have so many different variables controlling X vs O. `currentPlyaer`, `playerRole`, `playerX`, etc. I can't follow it, and I suspect this is causing the problem. Try to simplify this.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should not mix *presentation* with *game logic*. For instance, `checkWin` should be a function that does not access the DOM, like to read `textContent`: this is bad practice. All of your game state should be in a variable, and output to the screen should be dealt with in separate function(s).